# JQuery code is not working using PHP Code for Posts and Pages plugin for Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am made to use plugin PHP Code for Posts and Pages in worpress page.
I want to expand row details after clicking on it like in this example:       http://jsfiddle.net/ardeezstyle/4FKCa/1/

I can't do it using the plugin. After clicking the button row details are not expanded. Maybe someone is familiar with it and could help me?
Here is my code:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).delegate('input[type="button"]','click',function(){
if($(this).parents('tr').next('tr').find('div').length==0){
    $('[colspan="5"]').parent('tr').remove();
    $(this).parents('tr').after('<tr/>').next().append('<td          colspan="5"/>').children('td').append('<div/>').children().css('background','#f0f0f0').html($($(this).data('href')).html());
}else{
    $('[colspan="5"]').parent('tr').remove();
}
});
</script>

<style type="text/css">
    #content1,
    #content2,
    #content3 {
        display: none;
    }
    table {
        table-layout: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    td {
        border: 1px solid #000; 
        padding: 5px; 
        vertical-align: top;
    }
</style>

<?php

echo '
<table summary="test" cellspacing="0" id="master">
<colgroup>
    <col width="40px">
    <col span="4" width="25%">
</colgroup>

<thead>
<tr>
 <th>&nbsp;</th>
 <th><span>Customer</span></th>
 <th><span>OrderID</span></th>
 <th><span>Order date</span></th>
 <th><span>Order Total</span></th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<tr>
    <td><input type="button" name="" value=" " data-href="#content1" ></td>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td><td>10258</td><td>07/17/1996</td><td>$403.72</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td><input type="button" name="" value=" " data-href="#content2"></td>
    <td>Wartian Herkku</td><td>10270</td><td>08/01/1996</td><td>$1,376.00</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td><input type="button" name="" value=" " data-href="#content3"></td>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td><td>10275</td><td>08/07/1996</td>            <td>$15.36</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>

<div id="content1">
<h2>content for row 1</h2>
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>head 1</th><th>head 2</th><th>head 3</th><th>head 4</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>cell 1</td><td>cell 2</td><td>cell 3</td><td>cell 4</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis             egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante.     Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris     placerat eleifend leo.</p>
</div><!-- content1 -->

<div id="content2">
<h2>content for row 2</h2>
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>head 1</th><th>head 2</th><th>head 3</th><th>head 4</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>cell 1</td><td>cell 2</td><td>cell 3</td><td>cell 4</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis     egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante.     Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris     placerat eleifend leo.</p>
</div><!-- content2 -->
<div id="content3">
<h2>content for row 3</h2>
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>head 1</th><th>head 2</th><th>head 3</th><th>head 4</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>cell 1</td><td>cell 2</td><td>cell 3</td><td>cell 4</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis     egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante.     Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris     placerat eleifend leo.</p>
</div>';
?>
```

Comment: Have you checked if your JavaScript file is loading before jquery? There is a proper way to load scripts using 'wp_enqueue_script()` built-in function for WordPress.

Comment: What JavaScript file do you mean? All code that I need is placed here

Comment: Ok. So all this code is in your template file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you will need the $(window).ready() function, but I'm, not sure why you have all this extraneous code? You can just use the following which has the same effect, but is much more efficient.

```
$(window).ready( function() {

$(document).on('click', 'input[type="button"]', function() {

    var DOMtag = $(this).data('href');

    $(DOMtag).toggle();

});
```

});

Comment: This code is working!! But the details are display below table. How to display the details below corresponding row?

Comment: You will need to nest the actual divs within your original table-- Rather than make them divs, I would make them table rows (trs) and add the href tag to those trs. The end product will be 1 big table with hidden rows that are shown on the event fire.

Answer (score 0):

Your code relies on jQuery. You have to make sure that is being included. Also you should wrap it in the jQuery `ready` function like `$(document).ready(function(){...rest of your code`
Also I think wordpress uses `jQuery` instead of `$` so you'll have to wrap it and then give it the `dollar` in the anonymous function of `ready`.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(document).delegate('input[type="button"]', 'click', function () {
        if ($(this).parents('tr').next('tr').find('div').length === 0) {
            $('[colspan="5"]').parent('tr').remove();
            $(this).parents('tr').after('<tr/>').next().append('<td colspan="5"/>').children('td').append('<div/>').children().css('background', '#f0f0f0').html($($(this).data('href')).html());
        } else {
            $('[colspan="5"]').parent('tr').remove();
        }
    });
});
```

http://digwp.com/2011/09/using-instead-of-jquery-in-wordpress/